# Upload de dois arquivos de dois fields diferentes com multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, multer

Usando o [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) estou tentando fazer o upload de dois arquivos diferentes que vem de *fields* em `forms` diferentes e tem caminho de armazenamentos também diferentes:

```
let storageAudios = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, './uploads/audiographs');
  },
  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

let uploadAudios = multer({
  storage: storageAudios
}).single('audiographs');



let storageEstablishments = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, './uploads/establishments-logo');
  },
  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

let uploadEstablishments = multer({
  storage: storageEstablishments
}).single('logo');
```

No `controller` de cada rota para fazer os uploads tenho:

```
addEstablishment: (req, res) => {
    uploadEstablishments(req, res, function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.end("error");
      }else{

        // ...

        console.log(req.file) // retornando undefined

        // ...
      }
    })
},
addAudio: (req, res) => {
  uploadAudios(req, res, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err)
      return res.end("error");
    }else{

        // ...

        console.log(req.file) // retornando o arquivo esperado

        // ...
    }
  });
}
```

Como pode ser visto, o *upload* dos áudios funciona, mas o dos estabelecimentos, não. Estou fazendo algo errado?

Desde já agradeço a qualquer ajuda.